# Ajax settings for cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I'm relatively new to CakePHP, but I am proficient in Rails.

So I know the concepts of AJAX and everything else.

In a site that I'm working....a particular URL works fine when requested from the client/browser.

The same URL doesn't work when requested via AJAX calls.

Do I have to make any configuration changes?

Here is the site: http://www.resolutiontweet.com/

The login link is the AJAX-ified link I'm referring to.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I can see what you mean. If I try the following AJAX request - new Ajax.Request('/users/login') - from the Firebug console I also get a 404. Have you set rules for the security component which would cause an AJAX request to return 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have already tried this but clearing your file cache by setting the debug level to 2, then refresh page (click on the login link to make sure) then you can set it back to 0. When in 0 its CakePHP production mode and will use old cache (from the last time debug was > 0) stored in tmp/cache dir. Hopefully the problem is as simple as that. If not, post the login action code and we can have a look.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks. You were helpful :-)